# IPhone app crash (jettisoned) issue

Tags: iphone, image, memory, crash

I am having some trouble on my device for an app that was approved by Apple for sale on the store. I thought it was strange that it was approved, but since I know little about their approval process, maybe its not.

Anyway, here is the code I am using to download a remote .zip file and unzip it to the device:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function()
{

    var path = Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory;
    if (Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(path,'1-1.jpg').exists())
    {
    introScreen.remove(viewLoad);
    ntroScreen.remove(actInd);
    introScreen.add(view);
    introScreen.add(ci);

    } else {

    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'HFTImages.zip');
    f.write(this.responseData);
    Ti.API.log('INFO',Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory);

    var appDir = 
    Ti.Network.decodeURIComponent(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory).replace('file://localhost','') ;
    zipfile.extract(appDir+'HFTImages.zip', appDir);

    f.deleteFile();

    introScreen.remove(viewLoad);
    introScreen.remove(actInd);
    introScreen.add(view);
    introScreen.add(ci);

    Ti.API.info('The file has been extracted to:'+appDir);
    }

};
xhr.open('GET','http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23138095/HFTImages.zip');
xhr.send();
```

If it helps anyone, here is the crash log I got:

```
Incident Identifier: A2053187-D47E-459A-AA5E-B631D5B55282
CrashReporter Key:   ca558f421734b4d844e54d004ede3913830139f8
OS Version:          iPhone OS 3.1.3 (7E18)
Date:                2012-03-01 19:29:13 -0500

Free pages:        96
Wired pages:       10558
Purgeable pages:   0
Largest process:   Hooray For Today

Processes
         Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
Hooray For Today <cc527ca9b51937c5adbe035fe27a7b12>    9320 (jettisoned) (active)
    mediaserverd <3d3800d6acfff050e4d0ed91cbe2467e>     255
     dataaccessd <13d80b2e707acc91f9aa3ec4c715b9cc>     505
         syslogd <8eddddc00294d5615afded36ee3f1b62>      71
            apsd <32070d91b216d806973c8f1b1d8077a4>     171
       securityd <b9e51062610d27f727c5119b8f80dcdf>     243
         notifyd <591dd4dd804b4b8741f52335ea1fa4ab>    2027
      CommCenter <b4b87526ae086bb62c982f1078f43f81>     189
     SpringBoard <324939a437d1cca1fa4af72d9f5d0eba>    2158 (active)
      accessoryd <8f21c8b376d16e2ccb95ed6d21d8317a>      91
         configd <85efd41aceac34ccc0019df76623c7a9>     371
       fairplayd <a2eaf736b3e07c7c9a2c82e9eb893555>      93
   mDNSResponder <df1cd275e4ad434e0575990e8e1da4cb>     292
       lockdownd <80d2bd44c0bcca273d48ce52010f7e65>    1204
         launchd <a5988245aade809bf77576f1d9de42c5>      72

**End**
```

Can anyone see where I might have a memory spike or something else going on? It works great in the emulator.

Please help if anyone can. I cannot thank you all enough for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device is running out of memory and hence killed by iOS. I have no experience with Titanium, so can't give any real solution. You might want to test it with a very small zip file to check if that works.

It also depends if `zipfile.extract` is requiring a lot of memory for the extraction process. Hope this helps at least a little.

Edit: the reason could also be that the app was unresponsive for too long, hinting that the unzipping process blocked the main thread for too long so the watchdog killed it.